# JS: Appending elements to head - how to chain the methods?

Tags: javascript, dom, append, appendchild, createelement

I am a bit confused here. I was trying to do some basic DOM manipulation - testing it with appending a title to the `<head>` tag. This is what I wrote:

```
document.head.appendChild(document.createElement("title").appendChild(document.createTextNode("Test Title")));
```

However, the above doesn't work. If I split it up, it works:

```
var node = document.createElement("title");
var text = document.createTextNode("Test title");
node.appendChild(text);
document.head.appendChild(node);
```

Why is that, what am I missing?

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Method chaining works off the return value of the previous method.

```
var chain = {
    example: function (val) {
        alert(val);
        return this;
    }
};
chain.example('this').example('works');
```

`example` can be chained off of `example` because `return this` returns an object which has an `example` method.

In the case of [`parent.appendChild(child)`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Node.appendChild) the return value is `child`, which means that chaining will not add elements to `parent` further, instead subsequent elements will be nested.

Answer (score 1):

Append the title element, then append the text to the **appended** object. Note parentheses-

warning- The title element is a special case, only one title element is valid in a document

```
document.head.appendChild(document.createElement("title")).appendChild(document.createTextNode("Test Title"));
```

Comment: Yep, this is exactly what I was trying to achieve but I messed up the brackets. Thx! +1